# Programmatically Tracking Changesets in TFS 2012 API/SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and programmatically the [TFS 2012 API/SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)

We have a very simple branching strategy of $DEVELOPMENT -> $TEST -> $LIVE

In simple terms, I am trying to build an application that will allow us to view which branch(es) (if any, but in our case they always be) changesets have been merged into.

My results will be displayed something like:

```
Feature Branch A  - Development Branch - Test Branch - Live Branch 
38                          39               40            41
42                          43               44            N/A
45                          46               N/A           N/A
47                          N/A              N/A           N/A
```

NOTE: We don't do baseless merges.

I have been experimenting and I can retrieve which changesets are on $FeatureBranchA but not yet on $Development. And again for $Development -> $Test and $Test -> $Live. These are known as MergeCandidates.

Basically given changeset 38 below which method(s) do I have to call to find that it has been merged on branch $FeatureA and get the changeset ID 39.

How is changeset 38 and 39 "linked"?

[image: A screenshot of the Track Changeset window in Visual Studio 2012]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC451985.png))</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944170/determine-in-which-branches-a-changeset-in-present/